# Variable interpolation in user generated content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say for example I was building my own CMS for a restaurant and I had a page where the website owner could go in and write his own descriptions for each meal that were managed via the backend.

Let's also assume that each meal has a name and price associated with it.

How could I allow the owner to go ahead and enter something like:

```
<%= @food.name %> is made from the freshest ingredients and sells for <%= @food.price %>
```

Could I also extend that somewhat and introduce the concept of content blocks (similar to shortcodes in Wordpress) where they could also drop in something like `<%= show_reviews %>` into their own content as well?

If so how would that work I am totally lost on how to do that with user generated content.

Comment: There are many solutions to user-defined templates. Consider [Liquid from Shopify](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allowing the user to execute ruby code could be potentially very dangerous. I would create a set of mappings instead. For example:

- `[food.name]` would be replaced by `@food.name`
- `[food.price]` would
  be replaced by `@food.price`

and I would explicitly use `gsub` to replace all occurrences of `[food.name]` by `@food.name`. In conclusion, I think the safest approach to what you want to achieve is whitelisting the replacement patterns your user will use, and `gsub` them all.

Comment: That seems like a much better solution. Thank you!